# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter had been deleted,how can I override configure

Tags: spring-security

In the spring-security6.1 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter had been deleted,how can I override configure.I find one day that I catch the answer

After security 6.0, a large number of configurations have been marked with @Deprecated, indicating that it is difficult to continue learning without new tutorials. So, I have searched for a lot of information as well. In the spirit of learning new things, I have abandoned the old version of security and focused on learning the new features and methods of the latest version.

You may have encountered tutorials that guide you to inherit the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and implement its methods while learning Spring Security.

```java
public class MySecurityConfig implements WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated() 
            .and()
            .formLogin(); 
    }  
}
```

Clearly, this method has been removed. In security 6.1, to be precise, it seems that it was removed as early as version 5.7. I have asked GPT and searched on Stack Overflow, but I can only blame my limited knowledge. I couldn't find a similar method all day, but finally, after searching for a whole day, I found a suitable solution. Please continue.

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) ->
                requests
                        .requestMatchers("/user/student/**")
                        .hasRole("student")
                        .requestMatchers("/user/admin/**")
                        .hasAnyAuthority("admin:add")
                        .requestMatchers("/user/teacher/**")
                        .hasRole("teacher")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
            );
        http.formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll);
        return http.build();
    }
```

You just need to add this bean to implement URL restrictions for different roles. The rest of the methods remain the same as before. However, there is one thing worth noting: the previous http.authorizeRequests() has been deprecated. If you pay attention, it has now become http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> ...). As I have limited knowledge, I naturally don't know what it means. Additionally, the previous mvcMatchers has now become requestMatchers. There don't seem to be any other notable differences. I spent a whole day configuring this, and I hope that Chinese and international coders who are looking for answers to this problem can find what they are looking for here.

Comment: 有没有中国的友人，是不是不能写中文进这个问题里的

Comment: please use english, and what is your actual question?